# What is the Excel formula to count the number of unique customers per salesperson?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

See image below.  I use the following formula to count the number of unique customers on the total row of the table:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( -- (FREQUENCY(MATCH(C14:C20,C14:C20,0),ROW(C14:C20)-ROW(C14)+1)>0))
```

But I need a slightly different formula to count unique customers by salesperson for my summary section outside of the table.

[Image: Excel example table and summary section - need formula in yellow highlighted cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Bvi.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in C8,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$14:B$20=$B8)/(COUNTIFS(C$14:C$20, C$14:C$20, B$14:B$20, $B8)+(B$14:B$20<>$B8)))
```

Fill down.

Comment: That formula works.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Note my recent edit that should allow you to fill right for unique count of sales orders.

Comment: Jeeped - filling right that returns a zero.  Something is wrong.

Comment: Your blank cells make the formula much more complex. If you get rid of the blanks and make all **B** into **$B** then it will work; otherwise it is a new question since additional criteria to accommodate blanks is required.

Comment: Jeeped - what modification in the formula would make it work when the data is filtered?